# Entity 'ouml' error while using lxml to parse dblp data

Tags: python, json, xml

I am trying to parse dblp data(xml format). So far my code is :

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-  
from  lxml  import  etree # lxml import library  
parser = etree.XMLParser (load_dtd =True) 
Tree = etree.parse( "dblp.xml" ,parser) 
Root = tree.getroot()
```

I tried running the code and I get the following error:

```
Tree = etree.parse( "dblp.xml" ,parser) # Parse the xml with tree structure  
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3426, in lxml.etree.parse
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1839, in lxml.etree._parseDocument
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1865, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1769, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1162, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 600, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 710, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 639, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
  File "dblp.xml", line 70

  lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Entity 'ouml' not defined, line 70, 
  column 27
```

how can i resolve this error?

Note: I have xml and dtd files in same location.

Comment: And what does the XML document look like?

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered the same issue whilst parsing DBLP's XML database. In my case, I was missing the appropriate `.dtd` file for my `dblp.xml` (which provides the necessary information for parsing certain custom entities, including `ouml`). The top of your file should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE dblp SYSTEM "dblp-2017-08-29.dtd">
```

The `.dtd` file specified on the second line should be located in the same directory as the `dblp.xml` file that you're attempting to parse. You can download the appropriate `.dtd` file your XML file from here: http://dblp.org/xml/release/

```
$ ls
dblp-2017-08-29.dtd  dblp-2018-11-01.xml
```

Also, given the size of `dblp.xml`, you may also want to use `lxml.etree.iterparse` to stream the contents of the file instead. Below is some of the code that I used to obtain entries for certain types of publication within the database.

```
fn = 'dblp.xml'
for event, elem in lxml.etree.iterparse(fn, load_dtd=True):
    if elem.tag not in ['article', 'inproceedings', 'proceedings']:
        continue

    title = elem.find('title')  # type: Optional[str]
    year = elem.find('year')  # type: Optional[int]
    authors = elem.find('author')  # type: Optional[str]
    venue = elem.find('venue')  # type: Optional[str]

    ...

    elem.clear()
```